# Jasmine/jQuery keypress capture

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

**BACKGROUND**

I have a simple form within which the name cannot contain numerics.

So I capture the keypress:

```
// prevent number from being added in a name
$("#name1__firstname").keypress(function(e) {
    rejectCharacterIfNumeric(e);
});
```

Then use this function to check if numeric, and if so, `preventDefault()`:

```
// function to disallow numbers added into a text input
function rejectCharacterIfNumeric(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    key = String.fromCharCode(key);
    var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
    if (regex.test(key)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    console.log('foo'); // <-- not being fired
};
```

**THE PROBLEM**

I need to write a `Jasmine` test for this but it's not capturing the keypress.

This is what I'm trying:

```
describe("when text is entered in the input", function(){

    var fixture;

    beforeEach(function () {

        fixture += "<input id='name1__firstname'>";
        setFixtures(fixture);

    });

    it("it should not show if numeric", function(){

        var textInput = $('#name1__firstname');

        textInput.trigger(
            $.Event( 'keypress', { keyCode: 65, which: 65 } ) // letter "a"
        );

        expect(textInput.val().length).toEqual(1);

    });

    afterEach(function () {
        fixture = "";
        fixture = null;
    });

})
```

This test fails as the numbers are inserted into the input `Expected 0 to equal 1.`

I know the test is not calling `rejectCharacterIfNumeric(e)` as I've added a `console.log()` into the function which doesn't fire

**QUESTION**

How can I pass a keyPress so it fires the `rejectCharacterIfNumeric(e)` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textInput variable in your spec didn't have the event attached to it:

```
it("it should not show if numeric", function(){

    var textInput = $('#name1__firstname');

    textInput.keypress(function(e) {
        rejectCharacterIfNumeric(e);
    });

    textInput.trigger( 
        $.Event( 'keypress', { keyCode: 65, which: 65 } ) // letter "a"    
    ).val('A');

    expect(textInput.val().length).toEqual(1);

});
```

Comment: I'll accept this although not quite complete answer - trigger needs `.val()` adding as follows 

`textInput.trigger(
        $.Event( 'keypress', { keyCode: 65, which: 65 } ) // letter "a"
    ).val('A');` - thanks!

Comment: Good spot. I've updated my answer accordingly. Cheers.